# 5 inch device gets dimension from sw320dp instead sw480dp

Tags: android, user-interface

I have an emulator for 5.96-inch device. This device gets dimensions from folder `values-sw320dp` instead folder `values-sw480dp`
But, documentation says that 480dp: a large phone screen ~5" (480x800 mdpi).
Can some one describe why this happens

Answer (score 1):

> The **smallest width of a device takes into account screen decorations and system UI**. For example, if the device has some persistent UI elements on the screen that account for space along the axis of the smallest width, **the system declares the smallest width to be smaller than the actual screen size, because those are screen pixels not available for your UI.**
>   [Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources)

Facts of OP emulator device:

- **Size:** 5.96 inch;
- **Resolution** 480x800
- **Pixel Density** mdpi

[image]

> The pixel density is the number of pixels within a physical area of the screen and is referred to as dpi (dots per inch). This is different from the resolution, which is the total number of pixels on a screen. 
>   [image]
>   The `DisplayMetrics.density` field specifies the scale factor you must use to convert dp units to pixels, according to the current pixel density. On a medium-density screen, `DisplayMetrics.density` equals 1.0; on a high-density screen it equals 1.5; on an extra-high-density screen, it equals 2.0; and on a low-density screen, it equals 0.75. This figure is the factor by which you should multiply the dp units in order to get the actual pixel count for the current screen.

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

**Solution: to choose from  `values-sw480dp`:**
Edit the Pixels configuration to increase it to 720x1200 hdpi.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens because it's usually not about the physical screen size, but also about the screen pixel density.

```
px = dp * (dpi / 160)
```

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities